# AppleScript (or alternative) that checks running apps and closes the last opened instance

Tags: macos, process, applescript

I have an OS X app, let's call it `TestOSX.app`. This is its displayed name (taken from the `Info.plist` `CFBundleName` key as far as I can tell).

For a variety of reasons (it can be circumvented by copying the app to another place or by opening it from Terminal; it does not work if `CFBundleExecutable` is not the binary per-se but a script that sets up some stuff before launching the binary itself...), I cannot rely on OS X's built-in policy to block someone from starting a second instance of the app, nor can I use the `LSMultipleInstancesProhibited` key. But I do want to make sure that every second instance started by the same user is going to quit before being able to modify some resources. Different users should be able to run their own single instace of the app at the same time (this is why `LSMultipleInstancesProhibited` is no-go).

(I wanted to build a mechanism relying on `flock(1)` but it does not exist under OS X.)

So, the strategy is: when a user launches my app, first check whether an older version is already running; if there is, send this latest app instance (that the script has been executed "from") a request to quit, and bring the old instance to foreground.

I cannot use the name of the process per-se, as the app may use some embedded tools (like a proprietary updater) which will have a different name than the app itself. This is why something like this won't work:

```
tell application "System Events"
  set listOfProcesses to (name of every process where background only is false)
end tell
```

, as the identified process may simply say `updater` (which is a part of the TestOSX bundle).

I have a snippet, probably parts of the "big thing", but it doesn't work as expected:

```
tell application "System Events"
  set theProcess to first application process whose displayed name is "TestOSX"
  set theOtherProcess to second application process whose displayed name is "TestOSX"
  set frontmost of theOtherProcess to true
end tell
```

, this one always brings to front only the 1st app's process.

And I don't get it why it doesn't work as expected, as long as:

```
tell application "System events"
  set listOfProcesses to (name of every process whose (dsiplayed name is "TestOSX"))
end tell
```

returns both instances. I guess somewhere the mapping between the process and the name is being lost.

[Edit]
Tried to modify the snippet above using:

```
tell application "System Events"
  set theOtherProcess to id of second application process whose displayed name is "TestOSX"
  set frontmost of theOtherProcess to true
end tell
```

, yet I get the error:

```
"Can't set frontmost of 680102 to true."
```

(This may be because I have a script that actually launches the binary, as said above?)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I came up with an ugly solution.

The bash script that is launched by double-clicking on the app icon is going to check how many instances of my app are running (with the aid of an AppleScript). If the answer is more than one, the bash script will end, thus my whole app terminating.

My `launcher.command` script:

```
#!/bin/bash
val=$(osascript ./instances_counter.scpt "TestOSX")
```

and the `instances_counter.scpt`, making use of the argument I passed:

```
on run argv
    tell application "System Events"
        set theProcessList to every application process whose displayed name is item 1 of argv
        set noOfProcesses to count of theProcessList
    end tell
    return noOfProcesses
end run
```

That's it.